# Long vertical bar in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

```
\left[a | \begin{Bmatrix}b \\ c \\d \\e \\f \end{Bmatrix}\right]
```

[image]

I have an expression where the expression to the left of `|` is short and the expression to the right of it is very long. I've tried the following to make the vertical bar long enough to accommodate the expression on the right:

```
\left[\left.a \right| \begin{Bmatrix}b \\ c \\d \\e \\f \end{Bmatrix}\right]
```

But this did not seem to work. I've also tried `\bigg\rvert` with no luck.

Comment: `\middle \vert`. Though, in this particular case I'd actually think that `\Bigl[ a \Bigm \vert <matrix> \Bigr]` would look better. Scaling `[ | ]` to the size of the matrix makes whem take focus from the equation, which is something to be avoided.

Comment: `\;\middle\;` would be the answer. Can you please give more context for your need?